# How can i get a list of the Codenameone FontImages and descriptions, to render in a custom image chooser dialog?

Tags: image, codenameone

I am using CN1 to build my app and i want to create a screen where the user can search and select from the list of available Material Font Images. How can i get this list please, ie. i will need the char code ("\uE900") and the description to search upon. I pretty much want to replicate the dialog that CN1 built in their cool, new Guibuilder.

[image]

By using the same approach, this hopefully means the list will grow automatically as the CN1 team add more in.

I had thought about deconstructing the FontImage class text from Github into a manageable List but don't think this is future proofing.

Once i have this list then i can apply it to a grid of Button tiles using:

```
gui_IconButton.setIcon(
            FontImage.createFixed("\uE900", FontImage.getMaterialDesignFont(), 0xffffff, 20, 20).toImage());
```

Although perhaps there is a neater way to implement that gives it the same LAF as the image above.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was done for that dialog is this:

```
private static List<MaterialFont> getMaterialFonts(){
    ArrayList<MaterialFont> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new MaterialFont(FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, "3d rotation"));
    list.add(new MaterialFont(FontImage.MATERIAL_AC_UNIT, "ac unit"));
    list.add(new MaterialFont(FontImage.MATERIAL_ACCESS_ALARM, "access alarm"));
    list.add(new MaterialFont(FontImage.MATERIAL_ACCESS_ALARMS, "access alarms"));
    list.add(new MaterialFont(FontImage.MATERIAL_ACCESS_TIME, "access time"));
    ...
}

static class MaterialFont implements Comparable<MaterialFont>{
    private char icon;
    private String description;

    public MaterialFont(char icon, String description) {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MaterialFont o) {
        return description.compareTo(((MaterialFont)o).description);
    }        
}
```

Which is problematic. Since we don't have reflection this is hard to maintain as we add new icons. I don't think the list includes the new icons we added recently either.

I think a better approach would be a separate class that just includes the meta-data of the class which will allow the optimizer to remove the unused icons when the meta data class isn't used. This class doesn't need to be a part of Codename One and can be "auto-generated" with a script.

If you are a Unix guy like myself then this statement would generate the `list.add()` entries:

```
javap -classpath ~/dev/cn1/CodenameOne/dist/CodenameOne.jar com.codename1.ui.FontImage | grep MATERIAL_ | sed 's/  public static final char //' | sed 's/MATERIAL_*//g' | sed 's/;//' | sed 's/.*/    list.add(new MaterialFont(FontImage.MATERIAL_&, "&");/'
```

Then you can just do a MetaData header and footer and combine the output of the sed command together with a `cat` command.

Comment: Fair knowledge of Unix but i can work things out usually. I will have a play with those commands until something happens. Thanks